# Trouble setting up Xdebug in VSCode with Docker Containers

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, debugging, xdebug

I've been struggling to set up Xdebug for my PHP projects in Visual Studio Code while working within Docker containers. I've done my best to configure everything correctly, but I'm running into a couple of issues that I can't seem to resolve. I'm hoping the community here can provide some insights and guidance.

**Background**:

- I'm working with PHP 7.4 and Xdebug 2.9.4.
- I've verified through phpinfo() that Xdebug is installed and running.
- I can see that Xdebug is listening to incoming requests when I have the Xdebug extension active in my browser.

**Issues I'm Facing**:

*Breakpoints Not Working Properly*:
The main issue is that I can't seem to get breakpoints to work properly within Visual Studio Code. I've set up breakpoints using the VSCode interface, but they don't get triggered. Instead, I have to manually insert xdebug_break(); to pause the execution. What could be causing this discrepancy?

*Path Mappings and File Navigation*:
When Xdebug stops at a breakpoint, it fails to navigate to the corresponding file. My current project structure is as follows:

```
C:/docker/ (base)
  c:/docker/prj1
  c:/docker/prj2
  ...
```

The current configuration in my launch.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000,
      "hostname": "localhost",
      "log": true,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And my xdebug.ini configuration is as follows:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal"
xdebug.log=/var/www/html/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.mode=develop,debug,trace
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
  php:
    depends_on: 
      - db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      #args:
      #  - TZ=Europe/Lisbon
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 9003:9003
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
    networks:
      - app-network
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

I also don't know why my xdebug.ini has xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal" and wether I change "hostname" : "host.docker.internal" it stops listening at the right address.

However, when Xdebug stops at a breakpoint, it seems to try creating a new folder with the index.php file instead of navigating to the correct location. What could be causing this issue?

I've tried reinstalling both PHP and PHP Debug extensions within Visual Studio Code, but I haven't been able to resolve these issues. I'm reaching out to the community to seek advice and guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix these problems. If anyone has experience with setting up Xdebug in a Dockerized PHP environment and can provide insights or solutions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Changing

```
       "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}"
      }
```

to

```
 "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "C:\\docker\\"
      }
```

helped on the problem, now I can debug on GUI Breakpoints!
But still, I would like to know what is causing the errors I'm facing.

Comment: A few notes: **1)** *"`xdebug.mode=develop,debug,trace `"* -- this is for Xdebug v3, there is no such option in v2. **2)** *"`ports:       - 9003:9003`"* -- I assume you were trying Xdebug v3 before. Well, this is wrong. If you would read the manual: it's Xdebug that connects to the client (VSCode in your case) and NOT other way around. With the above you are saying "Docker, take port 9003 for yourself and forward all incoming connections inside the container". The issue is -- now VSCode cannot listen on that port for Xdebug connections.

Comment: **3)** *" also don't know why my xdebug.ini has xdebug.remote_host="host.docker.internal""* `xdebug.remote_host` is where Xdebug will try to connect to. `host.docker.internal` is your Host PC as seen from inside the container. Since Xdebug is the one that makes the connection to the debug client (VSCode in your case), it needs to have the right host/IP to connect to. And since the IP can be different each time you run the container, hence the standard hostname is used.

Comment: **4)** *"and wether I change "hostname" : "host.docker.internal" it stops listening at the right address."* Exactly -- because it's a VSCode config option, it tells on which network interface to listen for incoming connections. and `host.docker.internal` is to be used inside Docker containers...

Comment: I suggest you post your live Xdebug config (Xdebug section of the `php_info()` output) as well as Xdebug log content when breakpoints do not work. Could be some path issues TBH... But `"/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}"` SHOULD do for most setups by default assuming that your VSCode project root folder is mapped/points to `/var/www/html/` inside the container.

Comment: **P.S.** Your PHP 7.4 works with Xdebug v3.1 (https://xdebug.org/docs/compat#versions). It's easier to troubleshoot Xdebug v3 than v2 (that is not longer supported). https://xdebug.org/docs/install#related_content

Comment: On points 1) I guess it was one of the tries I tried! 
For 2) 'i'm currently using xdebug 2.9 and I'm able to debug.
3) Why if I have my launch.json configured with host.docker.internal instead of localhost it stops working?

I got it working... I just don't know what i done wrong to be able to work with such off configurations . 

Thank you for your replys aswell

Comment: I moved to xdebug 3 and resset everything up ! thank you very much !